# file_get_contents() and preg_match_all issue

Tags: php, preg-match, file-get-contents, preg-match-all

I am using file_get_contents($url) to turn entire webpage into string. Then use preg_match_all to change the words /user/ to /member/ for feature members. example:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/profile.php";
$page = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match_all('/user\/(.*?)/i', $page, $search);   
$total = count($search[0]);
for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) { 
  if($search[1][$i] == 1) {
    $user_type = '/member/'.$search[1][$i];
  }
  $page = str_replace($search[0][$i], $user_type, $page);
}
```

My problem is, if i place the above codes into /profile.php, the page keep loading forever. How should i do? Please help!

Comment: Why in the world don't you use `preg_replace()` or `preg_replace_callback()` ?

Comment: @Hamza How to use "preg_replace_callback()"? Can you write an example for me please? thanks.

Comment: Can you give a small input with expected output ? I see this if statement `if($search[1][$i] == 1) {` and then wondering what are you doing ?

Comment: @HamZa Actually i have a Mysql query inside the if statement to check whether the userid($search[1][$i]) is feature member. But i didn't post it here.

Comment: The expected output is, if the member is feature member, then "http://example.com/profile/member/1".

Comment: and if it's not a "feature" member ? Also describe when the member is featured.

Comment: Is the problem solved? If yes, please post an answer. If not, let us know more details.